# Heroku error on trying to redeploy old app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, cedar

I'm trying to redeploy this app https://github.com/Arepo/rails-blog on Heroku, which I haven't touched in a couple of years. I had a warning that I needed to update Cedar-14, so I went through the `Upgrading an app` steps [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-to-the-latest-stack#upgrading-an-app)

But when I input `git push heroku master`, I just get the following error message:

```
fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What's going wrong? I wasn't *expecting* 'heroku' to be a git repo, or at least not one of mine...

Comment: Does `git remote -v` show a remote named `heroku`? _"I wasn't expecting 'heroku' to be a git repo"_ - you were trying to do a git push to it...

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten that I needed to re-add the app on this laptop as a Git remote, with `heroku git:remote -a <appname>`